# where can a get a bundle of intermediate certificates?

Tags: macos, ssl, ssl-certificate

I'm writing an app that scrapes a bunch of websites, and its amazing how many of them have their SSL certs misconfigured. I noticed that on Chrome, and when I run my app on my mac, they have no problem connecting to sites that dont have intermediate certificates installed. How can I get a bundle of these intermediate certificates to install on my linux server (I've tried apt-get install ca-certificates, but it only gives root certificates). Alternatively, how can I export the intermediate certificates out of Chrome or Mac (I dont see them anywhere in keychain access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those intermediate certificates are downloaded based on information contained in end-entity certificates. If you parse end-entity certificates and retrieve location of CA certificate from Authority Information Access extension, you can download intermediate certificates as well. Exporting those certificates from the browser most likely won't help because from time to time this list will change and also because it's possible, that browsers just don't store those certificates permanently (i.e. your list will be incomplete).